# Backtrack Linux apt-get upgrade error

Tags: ubuntu, backtrack-linux

I was using the apt-get upgrade command when the battery of my laptop died.
It told me to use dpkg --configure -a and I did.
I also ran the commands apt-get install -f , apt-get autoremove and used apt-get upgrade again
But these are the errors I am getting:

for apt-get upgrade after I had already run dpkg --configure -a:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.6
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r8169
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 se-toolkit
 subterfuge
 w3af
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the end part as the entire output is huge.

This is the ouput for apt-get autoremove :

```
apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up se-toolkit (4.2.1-bt0) ...
svn: 'http://svn.trustedsec.com/social_engineering_toolkit' path not found
dpkg: error processing se-toolkit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up subterfuge (4.3-bt0) ...
tar: SubterfugePublicBeta4.3.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/subterfuge.postinst: line 6: cd: subterfuge/: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'installer_old.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `SubterfugePublicBeta4.3.tar.gz': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing subterfuge (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up w3af (1.2-bt2) ...
tar: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/w3af.postinst: line 4: cd: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/w3af/code/trunk'; please relocate
dpkg: error processing w3af (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 se-toolkit
 subterfuge
 w3af
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the output for dpkg --configure -a when i ran it again:

```
root@bt:~# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up se-toolkit (4.2.1-bt0) ...
svn: 'http://svn.trustedsec.com/social_engineering_toolkit' path not found
dpkg: error processing se-toolkit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up w3af (1.2-bt2) ...
tar: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/w3af.postinst: line 4: cd: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/w3af/code/trunk'; please relocate
dpkg: error processing w3af (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up subterfuge (4.3-bt0) ...
tar: SubterfugePublicBeta4.3.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/subterfuge.postinst: line 6: cd: subterfuge/: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'installer_old.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `SubterfugePublicBeta4.3.tar.gz': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing subterfuge (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 se-toolkit
 w3af
 subterfuge
```

The output for apt-get install -f:

```
root@bt:~# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up se-toolkit (4.2.1-bt0) ...
svn: 'http://svn.trustedsec.com/social_engineering_toolkit' path not found
dpkg: error processing se-toolkit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up w3af (1.2-bt2) ...
tar: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/w3af.postinst: line 4: cd: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/w3af/code/trunk'; please relocate
dpkg: error processing w3af (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up subterfuge (4.3-bt0) ...
tar: SubterfugePublicBeta4.3.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/subterfuge.postinst: line 6: cd: subterfuge/: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'installer_old.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `SubterfugePublicBeta4.3.tar.gz': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing subterfuge (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 se-toolkit
 w3af
 subterfuge
```

I would like to fix these.
I did try reading up this problem but they all asked to use these commands and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmmh ... maybe try this:

First:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
```

etc ...

Then if it's still not working, maybe this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --configure -a
```

or maybe:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all 'package with a problem'
```

(corresponding to:

> se-toolkit
>   w3af
>   subterfuge

)

What about dist-upgrades?

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I had once a quite similar problem (upgarde interrupted because battery died), which was resolved when I upgraded my release (from 13.10 to 14.04) ... but it was on ubuntu not backtrack.

Comment: Dist upgrade gave the same errors. I'll try the other suggestions

Comment: And bactrack is ubuntu based. It just uses different tools

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm often confused between Backtrack (based on Ubuntu, which is kind of based on Debian) and backtrack Kali (based on Debian)

Comment: Even I'd have to google that haha

Comment: sudo dpkg -P --force-all 'package' seems to have worked. Not getting those errors anymore. How do i know if something I might need wasn't removed?

Comment: Mmmm ... I don't know sorry. Try to run again all the update/upgrade/install needed commands ... And if you have problems maybe try to reinstall the packages. And try the dpkg --configure -a command too. I'm not an expert, I discovered the commands I gave you not so long ago (:

Comment: Well no errors yet. I'm assuming it's fine untill someone corrects us

Comment: I hope it will be fine ^^ I spend one day fighting with errors like that (and many others ...)